# Derivative of $(Ax - b)^T(Ax-b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I am trying to take the derivative of $(Ax - b)^T(Ax-b)$ and setting it to zero without expanding the multiplication, by only using matrix calculus. I knew the partial derivative of $x^Tx$ according to $x$ is $2x$, derivative of $Ax - b$ is $A^T$ and by utilizing the chain rule, $(f o g)' = (f'(g))(g')$ I obtained,

$$
2(Ax-b)A^T = 0
$$

or

$$
(2Ax-2b)A^T = 0
$$

However the dimensions are not lining up here, if I had

$$
2A^T(Ax-b) = 0
$$

it would be fine. How can I get this result? Is there a rule I skipped that allows the statement above to be the derivative?

Note:

From this [link](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~gildea/2013_Spring/Notes/csc446multivar_review_notes.pdf) I found out

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(g(t)) = \nabla f(g(t))^T \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}
$$

If I had $g(x) = Ax-b$ and $f(z) = z^Tz$ then I could have

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(g(x)) = 
2z^TA = 2(Ax-b)^TA = 0
$$

Take transpose of both sides

$$
2A^T(Ax-b) = 0
$$

So I guess my original chain rule was wrong. Does this look correct? If yes, does anyone know where I can find the derivation of the correct Chain Rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  With vectors and matrices the order of multiplication matters.  One way of seeing what's going on is to write

$$Ax = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} a_1 & \cdots & a_n \end{array} \right] 
 \left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{array} \right]$$,

such that $\partial Ax / \partial x_1 = a_1$.  Thus,

$$\frac{\partial (Ax-b)}{\partial x'} = A.$$

The result you're looking for is therefore

$2 A' (Ax-b)$.

Comment: Right. Chain rule will not give me $2A'(Ax-b)$ though, it gives $2(Ax-b)A'$ because the derivative of the terms in paranthesis must go after the larger derivative.

Comment: The chain rule doesn't work the same if you're taking a derivative with respect to a vector or matrix.  Just take derivatives with respect to each element of the vector and then put your result in a vector.